# t-sql: incompatibility between built-in boolean functions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Why built-in boolean functions behaves differently on `NULL` input ?
For example - this query:

```
select 'ISDATE(null)'                 as function_call, 
        ISDATE(null) as result union all
select 'ISNUMERIC(null)'              as function_call, 
        ISNUMERIC(null) as result union all
select 'IS_MEMBER(null)'              as function_call, 
        IS_MEMBER(null) as result union all
select 'IS_SRVROLEMEMBER(null, null)' as function_call, 
        IS_SRVROLEMEMBER(null, null) as result
```

gives us:

```
function_call                result
---------------------------- -----------
ISDATE(null)                 0
ISNUMERIC(null)              0
IS_MEMBER(null)              NULL
IS_SRVROLEMEMBER(null, null) NULL
```

So seems that `ISDATE`, `ISNUMERIC` behaves according to boolean logic, but `IS_MEMBER`,`IS_SRVROLEMEMBER` - behaves according to [Three valued logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic).
Shouldn't all boolean functions behave the same on NULL input ? What ANSI SQL standard says about that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't find it odd that these security functions (`IS_SRVROLEMEMBER`) would behave differently from system/datatype functions (`ISNUMERIC`) since these security functions are essentially queries and the results can change depending upon who is querying. The meanings of the return values, including nulls, are spelled out very well for all of these in the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174318.aspx).

More concretely, for the arguments to `ISNUMERIC` and `ISDATE`, you can test very well ahead of time if the argument is null or not, so I'm not sure that returning a null is necessary, or has much practicality.

For the arguments to the security functions, you may have non-null arguments, but the functions have been built in a helpful manner to return null in cases where the arguments aren't valid, not found, or you don't have the permissions to know the answer.

Much of this can certainly be seen as subjective, thus I have voted to close this question, however interesting it may be.

Comment: This answer seemed too large for a comment, so here it is.

Comment: @0x69 I find it interesting that you accepted this answer over mine?  Not to suggest I have a problem with the answer, just that it is a day later, yet summarily agrees with my assessment that a) the security functions you've cited are not in the same "category" as the other two and b) returning a NULL for eg ISNUMERIC and ISDATE has little practical use.  Yet it specifically doesn't address your question about ANSI standards as mine attempts to.

Answer (score 3):

Re ANSI standards, the latter two functions have nothing to do with ANSI SQL; They're MSSQL specific security functions. Which is not to suggest they don't have analogues in other DBMSs, just that they're not "typical" UML style functions or part of the standard.

I'm fact, a search on [this *reasonably* authoritative O'Reilly page](http://oreilly.com/catalog/sqlnut/chapter/ch04.html) about ANSI standard functions for the term "Boolean" returns no results. One may infer from this that there is no ANSI approach to such scalar functions' handling of NULLs.

The three valued logic is required in those functions to allow NULL to signify that an input is not *valid*. eg Refer to *Remarks* section of [MSDN `IS_MEMBER()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186271.aspx).

(This form of NULL return is not to be confused with eg aggregate functions that may return a value, or NULL if one of its inputs was NULL.)

There's nothing stopping you "wrapping" those functions to behave like the others, if that's what you really need. Eg `ISNULL(IS_MEMBER(someValueFromATable),0)`.

The former two functions return a meaningful Boolean value, as you've found.

`ISDATE(null)`, for example, returns false because null is *not* a "*valid date, time, or datetime **value***" ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms187347.aspx), my emphasis on *value*).

In the case where NULL is interpreted to mean "unknown", it would be semantically meaningful for `ISDATE()` etc to return "unknown" when the input is unknown, but not programatically practical; The need to "convert" the result (from all these boolean functions) from three-state to boolean logic is completely redundant when we already have a separate type-non-specific test for `ISNULL()`.

In comparing the two types of functions you've identified, the return for the latter ones shouldn't be NULL in this case, because while NULL isn't a date, it is still certainly a *valid* piece of data that can be properly examined by this function.

Comment: I expect IS_DATE(null) should return NULL. Because NULL means UNKNOWN/MISSING value. And we can't make assumption that unknown/missing value is certainly NOT date, yes ? Also following your logics `select LEN(null)` could return 0 - why it can't assume that non-valid input is string of zero length ?

Comment: It's not _my_ logic :-) Yes, NULL can mean _one or both of_ unknown and/or missing depending on the context in which the DB has been defined. Or it can mean, for example "we know there isn't one", which is different again. For example, Oracle (until recently, I think) couldn't store an empty string, it represented this as NULL (which meant you had to decide _which_ meaning you wanted a NULL string to take, and code around your design choice). If you want ISDATE(NULL) to return NULL then use a CASE or IIF to return NULL if the value is NULL else, apply the function.

Comment: @0x69 PS did you just down vote me for explaining how the logic works, because you wish it worked differently? :-) You asked "_Why built-in boolean functions behaves differently on NULL input ?_" I explained why.

Comment: I down-voted because of fallacies in your explanation. Exactly for this `What else could you expect from IS_DATE(null) than a FALSE return, when NULL is not a date`. You made 2 mistakes here. One is that I certainly CAN expect some different return from IS_DATE(null). Your other logic error is that we can't say that NULL is not a date. We actually don't know what it is.

Comment: @0x69 I _can_ say NULL is not a date, if I chose to represent "no date" as a NULL, eg an asset register may have NULL disposal dates for assets that have not yet been disposed. Your assertion that there is a specific meaning for NULL is not correct. Your chosen meaning is _a_ valid meaning, but not _the_ valid meaning. So yes, my logic (that we cant say NULL is not a date) is fallacious in the light of your incorrect predicates.  But yes, in light of multiple meanings for NULL my "what else can you expect" was not worded well, I will update.

Comment: Of course you can interpret NULL as you wish, but I think nobody knows NULL better than relational database model creator `E. F. Codd` :-)

Comment: @0x69 it's becoming apparent that you're more interested in philosophical debate, than an answer to your question :-) Codd defined E-nulls to represent unknown entities, not unknown facts. And if you've done your research on his proposed three state logic, you'd know it's rarely (if ever?) implemented in real world DBMSs. The functions you represented as exhibiting three state behavior do not do so in Codd's definition of the term.

Comment: @0x69 You downvoted "_Exactly for this `What else could you expect from IS_DATE(null) than a FALSE return, when NULL is not a date`_".  As you can see, I updated my language to reflect the alternate meanings for NULL.